# How to use disabled property on mat-list-item in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have mat-list which have mat-list-items, i make disabled Status named mat-list-item using [disabled] but it not works and give error like(Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-list-item') How to make disabled particular mat-list-item in angular 6 ?

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item routerLink="/base/notificstatus" [disabled]="payloadArray.enabled != 'true' ">Status</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item routerLink="/base/notifcategory">Category</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to stop navigate to that page you can do it using ponter-events

> The pointer-events CSS property specifies under what circumstances (if
>   any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse
>   events.

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item routerLink="/base/notificstatus"
 [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events':payloadArray.enabled == 'true' ?'auto':'none'}"
>Status</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item routerLink="/base/notifcategory">Category</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: Great stuff, I didn't know that CSS could disable the mouse events, but makes total sense! I added `.mat-list-item[disabled] { pointer-events: none }` to my `<mat-list-item [attr.disabled]="condition ? '' : null"` and it works flawlessly! TYVM

Answer (score 4):

Another way: you can use css.

**Inside html:**

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of itemList" (click)="!isContentLoading && loadContent(item.id)" [class.disabled]="isContentLoading">
```

**CSS**:

```
mat-list-item.disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Inside **controller**, you declare a variable, in my case 'isContentLoading', which value you can change inside method 'loadContent(item.id)', which is called on click for list item or for a button of an 'a' (anchor).

*don't forget '!important' in css, since mat-list-item has its own styling

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable it because a `mat-list-item` isn't clickable by default.

What you could do is to use `*ngIf` to show a `mat-list-item` with a routerlink and a `mat-list-item` without a routerlink.

Something like this:

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item routerLink="/base/notificstatus" *ngIf="!payloadArray.enabled">Status</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item *ngIf="payloadArray.enabled">Status</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item routerLink="/base/notifcategory">Category</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution based on recent project ...
Inside html: (some credits to @adrian)

```css
::ng-deep .mat-list-item-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
}
```

```html
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of payloadArray" [disabled]="!payloadArray.enabled" **>
```