# Highlight the sidebar item according the progress

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular11

I have a sidebar to display the job progress. Now I have three phases.

[image: phases]

At the beginning the project has not started yet, so I want all sidebar items are greyed out. I want the current phase is based on the previous phases completion.
On the right side there are three buttons. Here is the logic.

1. **Working on phase 1**. When I work on the phase 1, the Phase 1 sidebar item is active and the color is green. Phase 2 and Phase 3 items are still inactive.
2. **Working on phase 2**. When I click Phase 1 completed button then we go to phase 2, the Phase 2 is colored as green and Phase 1 is still active but just no color.
3. **Working on phase 3**. When I click Phase 2 completed button then we go to phase 3, the Phase 3 is colored as green and Phase 1 and Phase 2 are active but just no color.
4. When we go to the next phase, the previous phase items have their borders visible.

My ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.css']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  sidenavWidth = 10;
  ngStyle: string;
  active1: boolean;
  active2: boolean;
  active3: boolean;
  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.active1 = false;
    this.active2 = false;
    this.active3 = false;
  }
  submit1() {
    this.active1 = true;
    this.active2 = false;
    this.active3 = false;
    console.log('1');
  }
  submit2() {
    this.active1 = true;
    this.active2 = true;
    this.active3 = false;
    console.log('2');
  }
  submit3() {
    this.active1 = true;
    this.active2 = true;
    this.active3 = true;
    console.log('3');
  }
}
```

My html:

```
    <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav  mode="side" class="example-sidenav" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.em': sidenavWidth }" opened="true">
    <div class="logomain">Project progress</div>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item routerLink="1" [routerLinkActive]="[active1]" >
        <div fxFlex="10"></div>
        <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
          <h5 class="lead">Phase 1</h5>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>

      <mat-list-item routerLink="2" [routerLinkActive]="[active2]">
        <div fxFlex="10"></div>
        <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
          <h5 class="lead">Phase 2</h5>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>

      <mat-list-item routerLink="3" [routerLinkActive]="[active3]">
        <div fxFlex="10"></div>
        <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
          <h5 class="lead">Phase 3</h5>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <!-- <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    
  </div> -->
  <br><br><br>
 <section>
  <br>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click) ="submit1()">Phase 1 completed</button>
   </div>
</section>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<br>
<section>
    <br>
    <div class="example-button-row">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click) = "submit2()">Phase 2 completed</button>
    </div>
</section>
<br>
.<section>
    <br>
    <div class="example-button-row">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click) = "submit3()">Phase 3 completed</button>
    </div>
</section>
<br>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Here is the [stackblize example](https://angular-material-with-angular-sidenav-etrylt.stackblitz.io).

My questions. When I click the buttons the side bar item are not greyed out by the condition. Also I am not sure how to apply the green color to the working phase.

Finally I have many items instead of 3 items in the example. I don't want manually to set boolean values in the click events.

**Update**:

The correct editable stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav-etrylt

Comment: can you please share an edit  link to the StackBlitz so the sample can easily be forked?

Comment: @BizzyBob, sorry about it. I updated the question, the link is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav-etrylt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need a simple structure to represent your Phases with a property to indicate if it is completed or not.

```
interface Phase {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    isComplete: boolean;
}
```

Then, when you click a button, toggle the `isComplete` property.

You can define an array of `Phase` objects and use `*ngFor` to repeat them in your template.  This will prevent your template from growing when you add more phases.

sidebar.component.ts:

```
  public phases = [
    { id: 1, name: "Phase 1", isComplete: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Phase 2", isComplete: false },
    { id: 3, name: "Phase 3", isComplete: false }
  ];
```

sidebar.component.html:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let phase of phases">
      <h5>{{ phase.name }}</h5>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>

<section *ngFor="let phase of phases">
    <button
      (click)="togglePhaseComplete(phase)"
      [disabled]="phase.isComplete"
    >
      {{ phase.name }} completed!
    </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Then, you can use this `isComplete` property in your template to disable buttons for phases that have already been completed:

```
[disabled]="phase.isComplete"
```

You can also make a little helper function to determine if a phase is Active or not in order to display your green background color:

```
public isActive(phase: Phase) {
    // the first incomplete phase found is active
    const activePhase = this.phases.find(p => !p.isComplete);
    return phase.id === activePhase?.id;
}
```

Then just add `[class.green]="isActive(phase)"` to your `mat-list-item` (*assuming you defined a class named "green" in your css*).

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav-hruexh?file=app%2Fsidenav%2Fsidenav.component.ts)

Now, disabling the nav items for phases that haven't yet been active is a little more work because the `mat-list-item` doesn't have a `disabled` property like the button does, so something like this will NOT work:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let phase of phases" 
               [disabled]="!isActive(phase) && !phase.isComplete"
>
```

But, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52513761/1858357), you can create a css class to disable mouse events and display the item as disabled, so the code would look like:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let phase of phases" 
               [class.disabled]="!isActive(phase) && !phase.isComplete"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I might speak my question clearly. If so, sorry about it. I want to left side item(or tab) color changed along with the development of phases. The right side buttons should not changed.

Comment: No problem!  Just remove the bit I added to button element `[disabled]="phase.isComplete"`.  The sample does currently apply a green color to the left side tab.

Comment: That is fine, I want the left side uncompleted item are greyed out. Does the code have the function?

Comment: You can change definition of `.disabled` class to have gray color or whatever you need :-)

Comment: FYI: I updated the stackblitz to include the gray color.  Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button
    mat-raised-button
    color="primary"
    [ngClass]="
      phase.active1 === true
        ? 'active'
        : completedPhase.indexOf('active1') > -1
        ? 'pre-active'
        : ''
    "
  >
    Phase 1 completed
  </button>

  <button
    mat-raised-button
    color="primary"
    [ngClass]="
      phase.active2 === true ? 'active' : completedPhase.indexOf('active2') > -1
        ? 'pre-active'
        : ''
    "
  >
    Phase 2 completed
  </button>
```

Comment: sidenavWidth = 10;

  phase: any = {
    active1: false,
    active2: false,
    active3: false,
  };

  completedPhase: string[] = [];

Comment: onPhase(type: string) {
    if (this.phase[type] !== undefined) {
      for (let key in this.phase) {
        this.phase[key] = false;
      }

      this.phase[type] = true;

      if (this.completedPhase.indexOf(type) === -1) {
        this.completedPhase.push(type);
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Can you format your code with indent? It is hard to read. If you could edit in StackBlize that would be great. Thanks.